# How do I erase too much space from the homepage of my code

Tags: html, css, text, containers, whitespace

When I run my code the spacing is too much in the actual code , just like writing an actual note and giving a long spacious paragraph thats how it seems in my code .Don't know if it's the previous code thats causing the problem or what.Because my preview code was an  and i wrapped it around a container so i don't just know

I tried adding to the margin-bottom to my text which was being brought down a lot because of the too much spacing at the middle.So I thought if I could move the text up the area where there was so much space, if it might just as well clear up the space . But the results where negative,the more i pushed that segment of text upwards the more another space is being created below, I  even tried removing the container of my previous code to check if that was the problem but it still didn't work

Comment: You need to include the problematic code (and possibly a screenshot), right now everyone will have a hard time understanding what the actual problem could be.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example